# How Can I use "my documents" folder as sqlite dabase path?

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I'm trying to create my database file in 'my documents' folder but I'm getting an Exception

```
// get database path
string path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "mydatabase.db3");

// get connection
Db = new SQLiteConnection(path, SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite | SQLiteOpenFlags.Create | SQLiteOpenFlags.FullMutex);
```

Exception:
Could not open database file: C:\Users\myuser\Documents\mydatabase.db3 (CannotOpen)

Do I need to request any permission or something?

Comment: What happens if you remove the flags? Also, what package (NuGet) are you using?

Comment: same without the flags, sqlite-net-pcl 1.6.292

Comment: I'm using sqlite-net-standard 1.5.1